Programmatically alter Physically Based Material properties from Xcode
I cannot seem to find the way to alter the properties of a Physically Based Material created in Xcode. For example, I have a material in Reality Composer Pro called Skin_Material.

Now I can alter the opacity property of the Skin_Material with a slider as shown below:
@State private var skinOpacity: Float = 0.0

Slider(value: $skinOpacity, in: (0.0)...(1.0))
    .onChange(of: skinOpacity) { _, _ in
        // What do I put here?
    }

I think I won't be the first one to be clueless in this endeavour so any guidance would be great. I know there is a resource from WWDC that does this with a ShaderGraphMaterial Here, but this is not applicable to altering physically based materials.

Programmatically controlling PBR material pty
The following post contains all the necessary info on how to programmatically alter PBR material and MaterialX properties' values using RealityKit API. The main idea behind changing skinOpacity property's value ​​is that you must create an input node through which you are going to control an opacity.

Why don't you just close-vote the question then?
